# JavaScript clearInterval not working

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make page to scroll down to an exact element after clicking on a link. But after clicking it scrolls down to the end of a page and when I try to scroll up, it tries to scroll down.

So, It means that `clearInterval()` in my function is not working and I do not understand.  "why ?"

Here is the function:

```js
   function smoothScr() {
     var elem = document.getElementById("main");
     var elemPos = elem.getBoundingClientRect().top;
     var i = 0;
     var changePos = setInterval(changingPos, 10); 

     function changingPos() {
      if (elemPos == 0) {     
      clearInterval(changePos);
      } else { 
       i++;
       window.scrollBy(0, i);
      };
     }
    }
```

Comment: Why not use anchors?

Comment: `elemPos` is defined only once, when you're calling `smoothScr`. It is not automagically updated. You've to change the value in `changingPos`.

Comment: `window.scrollBy` in your case should scroll by 1ps, 2px, 3px and so on. try changing it to `window.scrollBy(0, 1)`, will this work?

Comment: @DavinTryon Is it possible to make smooth scrolling using anchors?

Comment: @EmchenkoMikhail not without JavaScript.

Comment: @Teemu, yeah, I thought so too. But nothing changes when I put `elem` and `elemPos` into `changingPos`. And it still scrolls down to the end of a page

Comment: @serge1peshcoff, alas, it didn't help

Comment: Notice, that `elemPos` doesn't has to be exactly `0` at the time you're checking it, it can be negative too. Hence checking `if (elemPos < 0)` might do?

Comment: @Teemu hahahaha, yeah! Ir works now!! Thank you very much! :D

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
if (elemPos == 0)
```

you will have to use

```
if (elem.getBoundingClientRect().top == 0)
```

In your example, elemPos never changes from its initial value.

Comment: well, it doesn't help :|

Comment: Do a console.log(elem.getBoundingClientRect().top) to see why it doesn't equal 0. Check the value in the console to see what the problem is.